# Add a Button to a GridView programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, gridview

I have a `GridView` and I am adding `BoundField`s in it using code.  Now I want to add buttons for edit and delete using code.  I know how to add a `ButtonField` to the grid using code, but I want to add a button, as `ButtonField` does not have the CommandArgument property.

Here is my `GridView` markup:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CellPadding="4"
                BorderWidth="1px" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None">
     <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
     <FooterStyle BackColor="#990000" ForeColor="White" Font-Bold="True" />
     <HeaderStyle Height="30px" BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
     <PagerStyle ForeColor="#333333" HorizontalAlign="Center" BackColor="#E2E2E2" />
     <RowStyle CssClass="test" BackColor="#E2E2E2" Height="25px" BorderWidth="1px" ForeColor="#333333" />
     <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2E2E2" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Navy" />
     <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FDF5AC" />
     <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4D0000" />
     <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FCF6C0" />
     <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#820000" />
</asp:GridView>
```

And here is my C# code:

```
 GridView1.DataKeyNames = new string[] { PrimaryKey };

 if (dtOutPutResult.Rows.Count > 0)
 {
     foreach (DataColumn dcDtOutPutResult in dtOutPutResult.Columns)
     {
         foreach (DataRow drDtColumns in dtColumns.Rows)
         {
             if (drDtColumns["OrignalColumn"].ToString() == dcDtOutPutResult.ColumnName)
             {
                 BoundField bfield = new BoundField();
                 bfield.DataField = dcDtOutPutResult.ColumnName;
                 bfield.HeaderText = drDtColumns["DisplayColumn"].ToString();
                 GridView1.Columns.Add(bfield);
             }
         }
     }

     foreach (DataRow dr in dtOutPutResult.Rows)
     {
         var buttonField = new ButtonField
         {
             ButtonType = ButtonType.Button,
             Text = "My button",
             CommandName = "DoSomething",
         };
         GridView1.Columns.Add(buttonField);
         break;
     }

     GridView1.DataSource = dtOutPutResult;
     GridView1.DataBind();
     lblMessage.Visible = false;
 }
 else
 {
     GridView1.DataSource = dtOutPutResult;
     GridView1.DataBind();
     lblMessage.Visible = true;
     lblMessage.Style.Add("Color", "Red");
     lblMessage.Text = "No Record Found.";
 }
```

Comment: use the gridview RowDataBound method. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx

Comment: i dont want to use that is there any other way as i have used in code

Comment: @DavidB can we do it except using the grid events?

Comment: Probably, but why would you want to? Thats what the event is for. Why dont you want to use it, im confused?

Comment: @DavidB there is no logic behind it.. i know that for what events are... i think i need to do it by event, as i am not getting any idea for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to add a [CommandField](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.commandfield.aspx).

```
CommandField cField = new CommandField();
cField.EditText = "Edit";
cField.DeleteText = "Delete";
cField.UpdateText = "Update";
cField.CancelText = "Cancel";

cField.ShowEditButton = true;
cField.ShowDeleteButton = true;

GridView1.Columns.Add(cField);
```

These buttons will send the CommandArgument like you want, and should trigger the RowCommand event (if you want to handle that).